# Color spectrum Image - How to create

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I want to create a color spectrum image for a project. How do I create an image like this in photoshop?[image: color spectrum]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to create a near replica in photoshop by using a rainbow gradient left to right.

And then creating 2 layers- one with black to transparent gradient in the bottom and white to transparent gradient on top.

That did the trick I think.

Comment: You can pull the same trick in other color spaces to obtain different spectra.